# My markers wont work on my istamap

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps

```
function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
    zoom:5,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker ({
            position: (51.508742,-0.120850),
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE



        });



$.getJSON("muziek.php", function (data){


$.each(data, function() {

$.each(this, function (key, value) {

    if (value.location != undefined){



        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(value.location.latitude, value.location.longitude);
        var images = value.images.low_resolution.url;
        var infowindow = new google.maps.infowindow({

        content: 
        "<img src='" +images+ "'>" 



        });







        google.map.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

            infowindow.open(map, marker);

        });

    }
});

});


});

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

My markers won't put photos on mine google map how can i fix this and put markers with the data from my istagram on mine google maps. I already consolelog my position but i wont get any result back.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest double checking your img sources. The following works fine for me:

```
var contentString = '<img src="[URL of image]">';

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: contentString
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  map: map,
  title: 'Test',
    //animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
});
```

Comment: i am getting images from istagram api

Comment: Have you tried using a publicly available image in place of what you get from the JSON object? If that works, then there must be something wrong with the way you parse your JSON.

Comment: i did but thanks koh for your help a friend of mine fixed the problem i dont know what he really did but it worked